# Norm of swapped power series in the unit disk

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Suppose $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_nz^n+\cdots$ is defined in the unit disk and $\|f\|_{\infty}\leq 1.$ Lets form another series $g$ by interchanging $a_1$ and $a_k$ i.e. $g(z)=a_0+a_kz+\cdots+a_1z^k+\cdots$. Is $g$ of norm less than or equal to one?if that is not the case can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: Almost any polynomial, suitably scaled, is either $f$ or $g$ for a counterexample.

Comment: If it were true, you would have it for any transposition of coefficients ((k,l)=(1,k)(1,l)(1,k)), so it would be true for all permutations of the coefficients with indices $\ge 1$. Thus, all $H^\infty$ norms of such permuted series would be exactly the same, which is sort of too hard to believe...

Comment: That's what I was also thinking; though  passing to the limit from permutations with compact support, to all permutations, seems delicate to me, as I only see local uniform convergence.

Comment: A question: what can be said about a function  $f\in H^\infty(D)$ whose norm is invariant by exchange $a_1\leftrightarrow a_k$ for any $k\ge 1$?

Comment: E.g. $f$ with all $a_k$ real and positive are OK, as they reach the norm at $z=1$.

Comment: @PietroMajer This came up as I was trying to prove a  theorem of H.Bohr. meanwhile was thinking about the same question that you raised. Can one classify all the functions in that Hardy space such that stay norm invariant under the action of "swapping."

Comment: If you have an interesting motivation, this is maybe worth another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, let us assume that the radius of convergence of $f$ is strictly larger than one.
By the maximum principle the absolute value of the analytic function $f:D\to\mathbb C$ obtains its maximum at the boundary $\partial D=S^1$.
Therefore we are interested in the function $g:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb C$,
$$
h(\phi)
=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^{in\phi}.
$$
This is a Fourier series.
The norm of this function is given by
$$
|h(\phi)|^2
=
\sum_{n,m}a_na_m^*e^{i(n-m)\phi}
.
$$
If the coefficients are real, we get
$$
|h(\phi)|^2
=
\sum_{n,m}a_na_m\cos((n-m)\phi)
.
$$
The question is now whether the maximum of the function $\phi\mapsto|h(\phi)|^2$ changes when we change the coefficients.

Let us take a concrete example: $f(z)=z+z^2-z^4$.
Now if $k=4$, the other function is $g(z)=\tilde f(z)=-z+z^2+z^4$.
Now
$$
|h(\phi)|^2=3+2\cos(\phi)-2\cos(2\phi)-2\cos(3\phi)
$$
and the corresponding norm for $\tilde f$ is
$$
|\tilde h(\phi)|^2=3-2\cos(\phi)+2\cos(2\phi)-2\cos(3\phi).
$$
If you plot these functions, you see that
$$
\max_{\bar D}|f|^2=\max_{\phi\in[0,2\pi]}|h(\phi)|^2=5
$$
but
$$
\max_{\bar D}|\tilde f|^2=\max_{\phi\in[0,2\pi]}|\tilde h(\phi)|^2=6.
$$
(One can of course prove these by hand as well if needed.)
Thus the function $\frac1{\sqrt5}f$ with $k=4$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: Very nice counterexample.